# What does "Si on veut une femme, il faut se faire un peu désirer" mean?

Tags: sens, verbes-pronominaux

I came across the sentence "Si on veut une femme, il faut se faire un peu désirer" and I'm having a hard time translating it. Literally it seems to me it means "if you want a woman, you need to be desired a little" (since [according to Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/faire#French) this is how "se faire + infinitive" is used, so that *se faire désirer* means "to be desired" and not something like "to make yourself desire/to make yourself desirous"). My guess would be that this is a way of saying you should keep your distance (since by being absent you'd be desired).

However, it seems not unlikely to me that perhaps in this context this could mean something else entirely (perhaps even it *does* mean "you should be desirous", i.e. express your desire, which is pretty much the opposite).

Is my interpretation correct? Is this a standard way of using *se faire désirer* or is this a little vague even in French?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're guessing right, in the context of flirting, *se faire désirer* is kind of like *to play hard to get*.

Comment: Thank you! That makes a lot of sense.

Answer (score 0):

You say "so that 'se faire désirer' means 'to be desired'"; this not correct; "se faire désirer" means "to act in such a way that the persons witnessing your behaviour will find it appealling and therefrom have a desire for you".

Your translation which precedes that, namely "if you want a woman, you need to be desired a little" is therefore not correct. There'll be several ways to put that and possibly none to satisfy everyone; but here are a couple;

- If you want a woman you must make yourself desirable to her.
- If you want a woman you must make yourself appealing to her.

You are correct though in saying that the meaning is not "to make yourself desire/to make yourself desirous".

It's very difficult however to adhere to your theory of the male playing hard to get ("you should keep your distance (since by being absent you'd be desired")) as this way of acting is —It seems we all know that— representative of the behaviour of women sometimes and looked down upon by the rest of society, whereas typically the male shows an outgoing attitude and knows where his chances are; he is never reproached with indulging in such "tactics".  this is more or less true in all cultures, I think, and the French do not escape the rule. On the contrary, "se faire désirer" for a male lies in the way of being true to his kind and being outgoing, in engaging in real interaction rather than in wrapping himself in a passive and glittering aloofness. This present point of view not being explicit in the sentence, your suppositions that it could be a prescription for passivity might very well be realised in the interpretation that some rare person might have, but that can't be what should come to mind for most readers; the traditionnal roles, although less important as guides of social behaviour, still predominate.

Whatever the modern attitude towards this behaviour, it is of the sort that in American psychology of days not too long gone by and probably still today was called "games" and "games" are not viewed as a desirable type of behaviour; society at large (the Anglo-Saxon societies in particular) does not like people who play games.

Comment: So you think the definition in wiktionary: "(reflexive, followed by an infinitive) to be, to get (used for a passive action). Se faire piquer. ― To be stung. Je me suis fait avoir. ― I got screwed." is wrong? Regarding "It seems we all know that— representative of typical female behaviour, whereas typically the male shows an outgoing attitude and knows where his chances are", I am not sure that's true, I think it is often suggested to men not to let it show how interested they are in a woman.

Comment: Anyway, thanks for your answer! Although I'm a bit loss now since the other answer says pretty much the exact opposite...

Comment: Here's another thought: even if "playing hard to get" is something which is usually women and not men are advised to do, I wouldn't interpret this phrase in the sentence "if a man wants a woman he should play hard to get" in a an unusual way. Perhaps it is an unusual sentence, but its meaning is clear.

Comment: @Salamano As far as I can see into Anglo-Saxon culture this particular attitude of women we 've been considering is not acknowledged as recommended behaviour, on the contrary ; it happens that there are a few that indulge in it and they are usually looked down upon by most men **and** women. I realise now that I misrepresented reality in my answer in saying "typical of female behaviour", this is an enormous exageration and I will change that.

Comment: @Salamano The meaning is clear in  "if a man wants a woman he should play hard to get", but that sentence is not the utterance of a moral precept; the immorality of it also is clear and one should not advise the use of such attitudes; that's not my opinion but a general view upon the matter. I do not share at all this opinion in the answer you refer to; you might as well counsel men to act as show offs in order to get the favours of the women they like: nonsense! Ridiculous!

Comment: right, so the only question is if the french sentence I quoted seems to be saying the same thing (regardless of how we feel about that sentence) :)

Comment: @Salamano I assure you that the definition you mention in the Wiktionnary has nothing to do  with "se faire désirer" and that your interpretations as found in your question are erroneous, just as I refute them in my answer; there is no other way about it. What would "be saying the same thing" mean ? Same thing as what ?

Comment: What I meant was that the question is whether "Si on veut une femme, il faut se faire un peu désirer" means more or less the same thing as the sentence "if you want a woman, you should play hard to get/keep your distance", and that this is separate from the question of whether this sentence is nonsense or not and from what the norm is. So I don't think the fact that men aren't usually advised to do this is relevant to the question of translation.

Comment: It's a little weird to me that you say my guess is so definitely wrong considering that the other answer said it was correct (and got 5 upvotes). Also since then I found another confirmation here: https://dictionary.reverso.net/french-english/se%20faire%20desirer.

Comment: @Salamano No, not at all, there are countless ways to make yourself desirable and playing hard to get, which is after all a despicable manner to do that and by which you might achieve just the opposite, is only one of them; no, it **does not** at all mean "playing hard to get". I maintain what I wrote and I am as surprised as you are both of what is said in that answer and of the five votes.

Comment: @Salamano I see that: Je crois qu'elle cherche à se faire désirer. 
I guess she's playing hard to get. This is translation of the type you call "free translation" and people say a little bit what they want, and sometimes way too much. You must beware of that: translation does produce errors. On top of that the reverso system is obviously a system of trials at translation which is subject to votes; if you do not find a good number of repetitions of a translation it is not necessarily too good. That translation is worthless as far as I am concerned (context  specialised to one single case).

Comment: @Salamano I feel bound to add a small comment in view of the conversation with LPH. The key question of what it is that will excite desire in a woman is for everyone to find their own answer to. There is a large spectrum of possible attitudes from fawning over her to being completely cold and aloof. I think "se faire un peu désirer" tilts towards "aloofness" because it's qualified by the "un peu" that gives me the idea that it's part of a game and that a little coldness can be used as bait but I'm not claiming I'm right and LPH, never one to doubt himself, is entitled to disagree strongly.

Comment: @petitrien There is the proof in my present answer that I can be  one to doubt myself; user Salamendo's objections  were right away recognised by me as justified and prompted the revision of my answer; You are  quite wrong again in your sweeping genéralisations.

Comment: @LPH.          That's me relieved!  I'm wrong, you're right.  Don't change, LPH, you're priceless!

Comment: Well, anyway, thank you both for helping out :)